# Filling table with datetime's incremented by one second each

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a `MyDatabase.MyTable.DateCol` with few thousand rows, which I want to fill up with datetime. I want each date to be bigger than the previous one by 1 second. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the structure of `MyTable`, and how do you know one record is before or after another?  What is the RDBMS?

Comment: Let's assume that in `MyTable` I have `DateCol DateTime2(7)` and `Id` columns. Also, it is MS SQL server.

Comment: How do you know one record should be positioned before or after another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample Table**

```
CREATE Table DateTable 
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),Name NVARCHAR(300), Data Datetime)
GO
```

**Test Data**

```
INSERT INTO DateTable (Name)
VALUES ('John'),('Mark'),('Phil'),('Simon'),('Sam'),('Pete'),('Josh')
GO
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)  FROM DateTable
)
UPDATE CTE
SET  Data = DATEADD(SECOND, CTE.rn, GETDATE())
```

**Result Set**

```
SELECT * FROM DateTable

ID  Name    Data
1   John    2013-11-06 20:34:59.310
2   Mark    2013-11-06 20:35:00.310
3   Phil    2013-11-06 20:35:01.310
4   Simon   2013-11-06 20:35:02.310
5   Sam     2013-11-06 20:35:03.310
6   Pete    2013-11-06 20:35:04.310
7   Josh    2013-11-06 20:35:05.310
```

Comment: @ojek in ROW_NUMBER() function use the column you want the datetime to increment by if its not your ID Column.

Comment: You don't need the additional `FROM/JOIN` in your update. You can just update the CTE. [See example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/17222/2).

Comment: @GarethD Thank you for the tip :) but will it not matter if in ROW_NUMBER() function it is Order by some other column other than ID ??

Comment: No, it won't matter at all, it could get complicated if the ordering is based on columns from other tables, but for a single table it doesn't matter what the ordering columns are.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of your ordering criteria, but you can use:

```
MIN(DateCol) OVER()
```

To get the first date, and

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateCol, ID)
```

To get the number of seconds to add (your ordering criteria may be different). Then combine the two to update a common table expression:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID,
            DateCol,
            NewDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 
                                MIN(DateCol) OVER(), 
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateCol, ID))
    FROM    MyDatabase.MyTable
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     DateCol = NewDate;
```

If you have no dates in your column then you can just enter a start date (`GETDATE()` below):

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID,
            DateCol,
            NewDate = DATEADD(SECOND, 
                                GETDATE(), 
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateCol, ID))
    FROM    MyDatabase.MyTable
)
UPDATE  CTE
SET     DateCol = NewDate;
```

Comment: I think that it should started by manually update the first record's datetime field and then the ordering will be done by the id ascending.